# Docker compose volume cannot mount directory onto a file (or vice-versa)

Tags: docker, docker-compose, mount, docker-machine, caddy

I'm using a caddy container with the following docker-compose configuration block:

```
frontend:
    image: zzrot/alpine-caddy
    ports:
        - "433:433"
        - "80:80"
    volumes:
        - ./share/etc/Caddyfile:/etc/Caddyfile
        - ./root/static:/var/www/htm
```

When I run docker-compose up I see the following error:

```
ERROR: oci runtime error: container_linux.go:262: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:339: container init caused \"rootfs_linux.go:57: mounting \\\"/Users/adam/code/projects/BicycleEvents-Web/share/etc/Caddyfile\\\" to rootfs \\\"/var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/9e45393ec987dcca75752736c2b4af323ce78838b4d9233059e4d24c6ada193a\\\" at \\\"/var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/9e45393ec987dcca75752736c2b4af323ce78838b4d9233059e4d24c6ada193a/etc/Caddyfile\\\" caused \\\"not a directory\\\"\""
: Are you trying to mount a directory onto a file (or vice-versa)? Check if the specified host path exists and is the expected type
```

This was working a while ago but I've recently upgraded docker-machine and tried rebuilding the containers.

docker-machine version: `docker-machine version 0.12.1, build c8b17e8`

docker-compose version:

```
1.6.0, build d99cad6
docker-py version: 1.7.0
CPython version: 2.7.11
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 0.9.8zh 14 Jan 2016
```

docker version:

```
Client:
 Version:      1.10.1
 API version:  1.22
 Go version:   go1.5.3
 Git commit:   9e83765
 Built:        Thu Feb 11 19:14:21 2016
 OS/Arch:      darwin/amd64

Server:
 Version:      17.06.0-ce
 API version:  1.30
 Go version:   go1.8.3
 Git commit:   02c1d87
 Built:        Fri Jun 23 21:19:04 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
```

Comment: Could you update your docker and docker-compose installations and try again? You don't seem to be running the latest versions.

Comment: @elyas-bhy I will try this as soon as I get home this evening. I know I can't install Docker for Mac, as I don't have a supported CPU, which is why I upgraded docker-machine only.